# What is the git equivalent to "p4 unshelve" to bring down another commit's changes?

Tags: git, version-control, perforce

Is there a way to do the equivalent "p4 unshelve" as git command to bring down another commit's changes into your own repository?

For example, is there a way to "unshelve" multiple git commits onto your local copy of a git repository and have them all as untracked changes?

Comment: `git stash` is  a git way to save/restore temporary changes.

Comment: Hey thanks @Serge +1 for git stash. You're right!  However I was looking to unshelve someone else's already committed change.  I updated the question to better clarify.

Comment: then you need to pull from the other's repo into a branch on your side.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple git commits in a chain that you'd like to apply, you could use `git rebase -i --onto DESTINATION UNTIL BRANCH` to use an editor to interactively pick commits in the range `BRANCH..UNTIL` that you want.

Note that if `BRANCH` is a commit hash, you'll end up with a detached head, which should be just as good (if not better) than having untracked changes.  If you really must have untracked changes, then simply do `git reset DESTINATION` afterward.

Answer (score -1):

To do this I used:

```
git cherry-pick <commits> -n; git reset
```

cherry-pick brought a commit's changes into my local workspace and the -n flag meant it was not already converted into a new commit.
For more information: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

git reset unstaged the files.
For more information: http://data.agaric.com/undo-git-add-remove-files-staged-git-commit

Comment: Seems like a good approach. But it's not quite clear why you wanted them to be untracked changes. Regardless, glad you found a way that worked!

Comment: For a machine learning / source code mining project.  Thanks!

Comment: @NateW That still doesn't explain why untracked changes are important to you.

Comment: @jamesdlin ha fair point.  I'm going to call "git diff" on them to see what changed, and I wasn't sure of a way to do that command if the changes are already staged with "git add" but I'm sure there's a way if I did more research on it.

Comment: `git diff --cached`